# Changing frame on animating object stops it from spinning around parented object

Tags: animation, timeline, dopesheet

I have made an animation of gears. When I change the frame 1-10 to 1-5 (so both gears and empty can go faster) in the dope sheet editor, the parent object and middle gear spins on their axis, but the outer frame doesn't spin on its axis anymore, just rotates around the parented object. But if I move the frame to 10 again, it spins again on its axis going around the middle gear.

I've included 2 files. one which is 1-5 frames, and one which is 1-10 frames.

[image]

[image]